# delete pagination cache from laravel 4

Tags: php, caching, pagination, laravel-4

I am caching my pagination with this code

```
Album::remember(3)->paginate(20);
```

But i dont know how to remove the cache from pagination before the expiration time. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't normally "forget" a DB cache, because you would need to know the hash used as the key.

You could retrieve that using the getCacheKey() method (it's definted like this):

```
/**
 * Get a unique cache key for the complete query.
 *
 * @return string
*/
 public function getCacheKey()
 {
  return $this->cacheKey ?: $this->generateCacheKey();
 }
```

Something like

```
$results = Album::remember(3)->paginate(20);
$key = Album::getCacheKey();
Cache::forget($key);
```

could work, but I admit I never used this procedure, I tend to assign a custom key to the `remember()` method and use that to forget it:

```
Album::remember(3, 'pagination')->paginate(20);
Cache::forget('pagination');
```

Comment: when using Album::remember(3, 'pagination')->paginate(20) returns empty data. Where as if i remove custom key then it returns full set of data. Is there any fix?

Comment: Uhm, does it work with ->get() instead of ->paginate() (I had issues in the past with that)? Have you tried the getCacheKey() method? If you're using a driver other than files or database you could use `tags` for the cache and flush them